# How to send an argument from one python script to another using subprocess.Popen communicate?

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, stdin, popen

I have two .py files.  The first file executes the second file, and also needs to be able to send an argument to the second file.

Here's the file1.py:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import sys

file_names = ['one.csv' , 'two.csv']

for f in file_names:
    process = Popen([sys.executable , "file2.py"] , stdout = PIPE , stdin = PIPE)
    process.communicate(f)
```

And here's file2.py:

```
def c(x):
    print x
c(f)
```

The first file successfully executes the second file, but doesn't pass the argument f to the second file.  I've also tried using process.stdin.write(f) instead of process.communicate(f) but this doesn't work either, and I'd rather use communicate instead of stdin because multiple instances of file2.py need to be executed at the same time without blocking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
process.communicate(f)
```

you *are* writing to the standard input of `process`; the problem is that the latter program must read the data from its input stream in order to make use of it.  You could change `file2.py` to something like:

```
import sys
def c(x):
    print x
for f in sys.stdin:
    c(f)
```

You seem to be thinking that `communicate()` allows the parent and child processes to share variable bindings; that's not the case.  As written in your question, `file2.py` would generate an error to the effect that `name 'f' is not defined`.

Comment: [This website](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Input_and_output#Standard_File_Objects) also recommends using sys.stdin and also mentions the option of using sys.stdin.read(), but when I run this, still nothing prints.  Does the file print anything when you run it? @Alp

Comment: You're also capturing the stdout of the subprocess, so if you want to see its output you need to either (a) not do that, or (b) print it yourself.  In other words, either omit `stdout = PIPE` from your call to the `Popen` constructor, or store the output using `out, err = process.communicate(f)` and print `out` yourself.

Comment: I couldn't get it working, but your comment still helped me to answer my question.  I ended up using [asyncoro](http://asyncoro.sourceforge.net/) instead of subprocess. @Alp